# $rootScope.$broadcast Issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to send a broadcast event. So, that are my needed files:

**html:**

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="selectItem(item)" href="#/app/item/{{item.id}}">
    {{item.name}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

So, when I click an item `selectItem(item)` is called on the controller:

**controllers.js:**

```
.controller('SelectItemCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope) {
  $scope.items = // define my items list;
  $scope.selectItem = function(selectedItem) {
    console.log("Item was selected");
    $rootScope.$broadcast('new-selected-item', {selectedItem});
    console.log('Message sent');
  }
})
.controller('DetailItemCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope) {
  console.log('DetailItemCtrl started');
  $scope.$on('new-selected-item', function(event, args) { 
    console.log(Message received);
    console.log(args);
  }
});
```

Of course my app.js links that url to the controller:

**app.js:**

```
.state('app.item-detail', {
  url: '/item/:itemId',
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/detail.html',
      controller: 'DetailItemCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

So, when I select an item, my console log is:

```
Message sent
DetailItemCtrl
```

I don't know why I cannot get the event.

Comment: is `scope.$on` vs `$scope.$on` a typo in the question body or in your live code?

Comment: No... sorry, It's really `$scope`. I'll update the question

Comment: just wanted to make sure before you got a bunch of answers telling you the typo was to blame.

Comment: Sounds to me like the first controller that broadcasts is in a different state (url) than the receiving one. Controllers can't do anything if they are not active in the view. You probably want to use a  service to share data across app

Comment: The controller are in different states... So, let  me check if I understand: when I'm sending the event, `DetailItemCtrl` is not active, so it cannot get the event. When I change the state and active the controller, the event was already sent. Is it?

Comment: Even if `DetailItemCtrl` was already started earlier?

Comment: Don't you need to use the $rootScope as a dependency and then listen there?  I don't remember the event being propagated down every single scope (but I could be wrong)

Comment: Each time you use a controller it is a new instance. When it is no longer in view the instance is destroyed. So in short...a controller assigned to another state doesn't even exist to receive the event

Comment: @Casey read the docs to answer that yourself. broadcast goes to all descendents and emit goes to all ancestors

Comment: @charlietfl Well, if I were going to bother to dig through the docs like that I would have written an answer instead of a one-off comment.

Comment: It really can't work, because I'm changing the state and so I'm creating a new controller that wasn't active when the event was sent. But if I click on the same item, calling the same state and getting the same controller, I still cannot get the event. And in that case, the controller had been created when the event was sent. It should have be able to get the event, or not?

Answer (score 0):

When your trigger the ng-click the controller is no longer active so any actions called from it(  selectItem(item))  will not get fired.  If you need something to hold state and communicate between controllers you should use a service. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Comment: Ok. I got it. I was trying that approach because I had another problem using just a service to communicate.

Comment: Ok. I got it. I was trying that approach because I had another problem using just a service to communicate between controllers when I'm using tabs.
In short, when I call a tab controller,  the controller that support the tabs doesn't reload to get the needed information. 
So I thought to use a broadcast event to call that controller to reload.
I explained it on another question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37715167/ionic-reload-controller-issues)